# How do I get this symbol (relation)?

Tags: symbols

How can I reproduce this symbol in Latex which stands for a specific relation between two variables?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The simplest would be to do it with `array`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER**

Based on follow up comment and edit from the OP, it would seem the relation is desired in a scriptstyle format.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,scalerel}
\newcommand\specrel[2]{%
  \mathrel{\stretchleftright{|}
  {\mkern-5mu\vcenter{\hbox{$\scriptstyle\frac
    {\,#1\vphantom{X}\,}{\,#2\vphantom{X^{x}}\,}$}}}
  {.}}
}
\begin{document}
\[
(q_0,x)\specrel{*}{A} (p,\lambda)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here, I just kern over a widened `\frac` to a free-standing `\Big|`.  If one preferred a taller vertical bar, the `\Big` could be replaced with a `\bigg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\specrel[2]{%
  \Big|\mkern-5mu\frac{~#1~}{~#2~}
}
\begin{document}
\[
\specrel{*}{M}
\]\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer, I think the picture I appended to my post might have been a bit misleading concerning the scaling. I edited it.

Comment: @Descrates Please see my revised answer.

Comment: thanks a lot for your taking your time, nice answer!